# How can i access ECB Dataflow? TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, sdmx

I am using Request package form pandasdmx library to to access some exchange rates from the European Central Bank. I tried to follow the stepts highlighted in the following walkthrough: https://pandasdmx.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0/walkthrough.html# bur it is giving me an error when i try to access the different dataflows. This is the code that i am using:

```
import pandasdmx as sdmx
ecb = sdmx.Request('ECB')
ecb_via_proxy = sdmx.Request('ECB',proxies={'http': 'http://1.2.3.4:5678'})
flow_msg = ecb.dataflow()


flow_msg = ecb.dataflow()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-9011799aab2e>", line 1, in <module>
    flow_msg = ecb.dataflow()

  File "C:\Users\gcperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasdmx\api.py", line 361, in get
    base_url, params=params, headers=headers, fromfile=fromfile)

  File "C:\Users\gcperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasdmx\remote.py", line 98, in get
    url, params=params, headers=headers)

  File "C:\Users\gcperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandasdmx\remote.py", line 118, in request
    with closing(requests.get(url, params=params, **cur_config)) as response:

  File "C:\Users\gcperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\gcperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\gcperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\gcperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []

  File "C:\Users\gcperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []

  File "C:\Users\gcperez\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 166, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded {} redirects.'.format(self.max_redirects), response=resp)

TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

I have used this kind of access many times before and nothing went wrong. ¿Anyone knows what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ECB changed its web service URL, and the version of `pandaSDMX` that you have does not have the current URL. I would suggest to use the [`sdmx1`](https://pypi.org/project/sdmx1/) package in which this issue was fixed > 7 months ago ([see the diff here](https://github.com/khaeru/sdmx/blame/master/sdmx/sources.json#L15)):

```sh
$ pip install sdmx1
```

```py
import sdmx

ECB = sdmx.Client("ECB")
flow_msg = ECB.dataflow()   

print(repr(flow_msg))
```

gives:

```
<sdmx.StructureMessage>                       
  <Header>                                                                                        
    id: 'IREF508443'                                                                              
    prepared: '2021-03-04T09:40:40+00:00'
    receiver: <Agency not_supplied>
    sender: <Agency Unknown>
    source: 
    test: False
  response: <Response [200]>
  DataflowDefinition (71): AME BKN BLS BNT BOP BSI BSP CBD CBD2 CCP CIS...
  DataStructureDefinition (55): ECB_AME1 ECB_BKN1 ECB_BLS1 ECB_BOP_BNT ...
```